# Trouble calculating perimeter of a polygon from reading x, y coordinate input into arrays

Tags: c, arrays, coordinates, distance

Having trouble with program that calculates the perimeter of a polygon from an input of (x,y) coordinates. I need to use arrays and I'm not very confident with them. Mostly having trouble with reading the values into the array from a .txt file (using <) and also how to use the last point and first point to close off the polygon.

The input is:

```
3  1.0 2.0  1.0 5.0  4.0 5.0
5  1.0 2.0  4.0 5.0  7.8 3.5  5.0 0.4  1.0 0.4
4  1.0 0.4  0.4 0.4  0.4 3.6  1.0 3.6
0
```

Where the first number in each row indicates the number of points (npoints) and then followed by the coordinates themselves which are in clear groups of two i.e. (x,y).
Each new row indicates a new polygon needing to be read.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_PTS 100
#define MAX_POLYS 100
#define END_INPUT 0


double 
getDistance(int npoints, double x[], double y[]) {
    double distance = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < npoints; ++i) {
        int j =; // I'm stuck here
        distance = sqrt((x[i]-x[j]) * (x[i]-x[j]) + (y[i]-y[j]) *(y[i]-y[j]));
    }
    return distance;
}

int 
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int npoints, iteration = 0;
    double x[MAX_PTS], y[MAX_PTS];
    double perimeter = 0.0;

    if (npoints == END_INPUT){

        scanf("%d", &npoints);

        // start with 0 value of parameter.     
        for (iteration = 0; iteration < npoints; ++iteration) {
            scanf("%lf %lf", &(x[iteration]), &(y[iteration]));
            // take input for new-point.
            // for next iteration, new-point would be first-point in getDistance        
        }

        perimeter += getDistance(npoints, x, y); 

        perimeter += getDistance(); // stuck here
        // need to add the perimeter
        // need to complete the polygon with last-edge joining the last-point
        // with initial-point but not sure how to access array


        printf("perimeter = %2.2f m\n", perimeter);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output for the first polygon should be 10.24m
If anyone could give me a hand that would be great, I'm quite stumped

Comment: You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you use the local variable `npoints` before it's initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. After adding the file input, just a few tweaks here and there. Most importantly, how to make the array point wrap back to the front.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_PTS 100

double getDistance(int npoints, double x[], double y[]) {
    double distance = 0.0, dx, dy;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < npoints; ++i) {
        dx = x[(i+1) % npoints] - x[i];                  // wrap the index
        dy = y[(i+1) % npoints] - y[i];
        distance += sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);             // accumaulate
    }
    return distance;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int npoints, point;
    double x[MAX_PTS], y[MAX_PTS];
    double perimeter;
    FILE *fp;

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("No file name supplied\n");
        return 1;   
    }
    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "rt")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        return 1;   
    }

    while (1) {
        if (1 != fscanf(fp, "%d", &npoints)) {           // check result
            printf("Error reading number of sides\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (npoints == 0)
            break;                                       // end of data
        if (npoints < 3 || npoints > MAX_PTS) {          // check range
            printf("Illegal number of sides %d\n", npoints);
            return 1;
        }

        for (point = 0; point < npoints; ++point) {
            if (2 != fscanf(fp, "%lf %lf", &x[point], &y[point])) { // check result
                printf("Error reading coordinates of %d-sided polygon\n", npoints);
                return 1;
            }
        }

        perimeter = getDistance(npoints, x, y);          // include args
        printf("perimeter = %2.2f\n", perimeter);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
>test polydata.txt
perimeter = 10.24
perimeter = 18.11
perimeter = 7.60
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the test of `npoints == END_INPUT` in `main()`.  It serves no purpose and, since `npoints` is uninitialised, gives undefined behaviour.

As to the question you asked, assuming the points represent a polygon with no edges crossing over, the distance will be the sum of distances between adjacent points (`0->1`, `1->2`, .....,  `npoint-2 -> npoints-1`, `npoints-1 -> 0`).

The only special one of these is the last.   Other than the last, the distance is being computed between point `i` to point `i + 1`.

That suggests `j` is `i+1` for `i = 0` to `npoints-2`.   Then, for `i == npoints-1`, `j` will be equal to `0`.

Writing code to implement that is trivial.